# C# Macro - CS1501 error for API - Linnworks

Tags: c#

I'm working on a Macro for Linnworks (order management software) and I am stuck at the final part of the macro. Their support isn't very responsive so hoping someone here might be able to help.

```
using LinnworksAPI;
using LinnworksMacroHelpers.Classes;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace LinnworksMacro
{
    public class LinnworksMacro : LinnworksMacroHelpers.LinnworksMacroBase
    {
        public void Execute(Guid[] OrderIds, decimal DPDMinimumCharge, decimal DPDPerParcel, decimal DPD_Red_Fuel, decimal DPDSurcharges, decimal DPDLocalConsignment, decimal DPDLocalAdditionalKG, decimal DPDLocalFuel)
        {
            try
            {
                decimal DPDRed = 0;
                decimal DPDLocal = 0;
                string Courier = "Blue";
                var OrderID = OrderIds;

                var OrderTotalWeight = int.Parse($"SELECT TotalWeight FROM OrderPackaging WHERE fkOrderId = '{OrderIds}';");
                var BoxCount = int.Parse($"SELECT SplitPackageCount FROM OrderPackaging WHERE fkOrderId = '{OrderIds}';");

                if (BoxCount == 1)
                {
                    DPDRed = (DPDMinimumCharge + DPDSurcharges) * DPD_Red_Fuel;
                }
                
                else
                {
                    DPDRed = ((DPDPerParcel * BoxCount) + (DPDSurcharges * BoxCount)) * DPD_Red_Fuel;
                }

                
                if (OrderTotalWeight < 15)
                {
                    DPDLocal = (DPDLocalConsignment + (BoxCount * DPDSurcharges)) * DPDLocalFuel;
                }
                else
                {
                    DPDLocal = (DPDLocalConsignment + ((OrderTotalWeight - 15) * DPDLocalAdditionalKG) + (BoxCount * DPDSurcharges)) * DPDLocalFuel;
                }
                
                if (DPDRed < DPDLocal)
                {
                    Api.OpenOrders.AssignOrderIdentifier(OrderIds, "DPD Red");
                }
                else
                {
                    Courier = "DPD Local";
                    Logger.WriteInfo(Courier);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.WriteError(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                Logger.WriteInfo("Macro Finished");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My issue is the line

`Api.OpenOrders.AssignOrderIdentifier(OrderIds, "DPD Red");`

It keeps returning
**ID: CS1501, Message: No overload for method 'AssignOrderIdentifier' takes 2 arguments, Location: @((50, 36)), Severity: Error**

The controller for this API call is:

```
  public AssignResult AssignOrderIdentifier(ChangeOrderIdentifierRequest request)
        {
            var response = GetResponse("OpenOrders/AssignOrderIdentifier", "request=" + System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(JsonFormatter.ConvertToJson(request)) + "");
            return JsonFormatter.ConvertFromJson<AssignResult>(response);
        }
```

I will admit I am not familiar with C# and have been fumbling my way though this so any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Tried changing the layout of the API call and still no luck. Tried asjusting the layout of the text and don't think it's syntax.

Answer (score 0):

you are passing in `(OrderIds, "DPD Red")`
you may only pass in `(ChangeOrderIdentifierRequest request)` --> a single item of type ChangeOrderIdentifierRequest named '*request*'

I suspect that there is a way to create a new (instantiate) ChangeOrderIdentifierRequest ....
so try something in the lines of

```
Api.OpenOrders.AssignOrderIdentifier(new ChangeOrderIdentifierRequest() {OrderIds = OrderIds, 
Text = "DPD Red"});
```

the names of the properties above (***OrderIds*** and ***Text***) are very likely different, see what comes up in your intellisense